# Unload to S3 with partition

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

When unloading data from Redshift to S3 using a partition, how to not have the partition column name as part of the forder name. For example partition on a date column "dt" would created a folder called "dt = 2020-01-01/". How to have the folder named instead "2020-01-01"?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, since the partitions are identified by the folder name, which has to include the column name.